# github cloning prevented by AWS S3, how to give access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, github, amazon-s3

I have a rails app on heroku connected to AWS S3 for file storage. One of my acquaintances tried to check out and help me out with a feature, but ran into the following problem: "I tried cloning down your app to play around with it but I seem to need aws keys to get it up and running." I use figaro for local env and heroku config for production. What is the good way to solve this problem? Giving temporary access somehow or sharing the github repo first then taking away the access later?

UPDATE

config/init/carrierwave:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  #config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',                        # required
    aws_access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],                        # required
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']                        # required
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']                          # required
  #config.fog_public     = false                                        # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" } # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

uploader:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  if Rails.env.production?
    storage :fog
  else
    storage :file
  end
```

Comment: Do you want your friend to be **able** to upload files to your S3 bucket?  In other words, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Not necessarily. She is just trying to play around w/ the app since one of the features doesn't work properly. So she would clone it and fix my problem which is not connected to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever plugin you're using for file uploading, it will have a little config block, or options hash, which you set when you reference it within a model.  She should change this so that instead of using the amazon s3 options, it saves files in the local filesystem.  Without any details of which file storage system you are using i can't give a more detailed answer.

For example, if you're using attachment_fu, you will have an option like

```
:storage => :s3
```

and she should change this to

```
:storage => :file_system
```

and then add any other options which are necessary eg saying which folder to store the files in.

Comment: I updated the question, I hope you asked for this one. If I simply invited her to the repo, wouldn't it solve the problem?